# What is the distribution of the residuals $\hat{e}_i$ in linear regression?

Tags: regression, distributions, linear-model, residuals

Suppose we perform linear regression in some data and the model is correct (Y is a linear combination of X plus a normal iid error term).  We know by assumption that the $e_i\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$. But what about the residuals $\hat{e}_i=Y_i-X_i\hat b$? what is their distribution and why?

Comment: For much more about this subject search our site for [posts about residual distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=residual+normal*+distribut*+is%3Aanswer+score%3A2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'hat' matrix $H=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ is so named because $\hat Y=HY$. This means $Y-\hat Y = (I-H)Y$, where $I$ is an identity matrix.

If  you multiple an $N(0,V)$ vector by a matrix $A$ you get an $N(0,A^TVA)$ vector.  Applying this with $A=I-H$ and $V=\sigma^2I$, we have
$$\hat e\sim N\left(0, \sigma^2(I-H)^T(I-H)\right)$$
So, the residuals are multivariate Normally distributed, but they aren't independent and they don't all have the same variance

Comment: FWIW $(I-H)^T(I-H)=I-H$

Comment: will sigma^2 actually be s^2 here?

Comment: No, the quantity on the right-hand side of $\sim$ is the true distribution, not an estimator